# How to create checkbox looks like font-awesome glyphicon

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I want to create a font-awesome `glyph-icon` which act like checkbox, this means that I need to create a checkbox, which need to disguise as font-awesome icon.

I don't need to have a label for current checkbox,just font-awesome icon which turn on and off.
check state, icon is on color one. uncheck state icon is on color two.

check state:
[image]
uncheck state:
[image]

How can I do it?!

Comment: Can you give an example of what the checked\uncheked states would look like?

Comment: Is this what you want? [https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/yILjk/](https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/yILjk/)

Comment: check state, icon is on color one.
uncheck state icon is on color two.

Comment: no @GunWanderer that is not what I mean.

Comment: @Brk can you provide screenshots or code of your attempts?

Comment: I provide the screenshots please have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do achieve this even without Javascript.

```
#checkbox{
  background:#2f8cab;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:15px 18px;
  border-radius:2px;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#checkbox-element{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:99999;
  opacity:0;
}

#checkbox>input[type='checkbox']+i{
  color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2); // color 1
}

#checkbox>input[type='checkbox']:checked+i{
  color:#fff; //color 2
}
```

And here's the markup,

```
<span id="checkbox">
  <input id="checkbox-element" type="checkbox"/>  
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i>
</span>
```

Have a look at this demo, http://jsbin.com/dusokagise/edit?html,css,output

For Inspiration: https://lokesh-coder.github.io/pretty-checkbox/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need? An **'on'** / **'off'** state?
https://jsfiddle.net/GunWanderer/k11ajrru/4/

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="item"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i></a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i></a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></a></li>   
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
body {
    padding: 20px;
}
#menu {
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
#menu li {
    background-color: #2D5F8B;
    float:left;
    color:#fff;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align:center;
}
#menu .item a > .glyphicon { color:#3979B2;}
#menu .item.active a > .glyphicon { color:#fff;}
a,a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
.active {
    background-color: #3979B2!important;
}
</style>
```

**jQuery script:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu .item a").click(function(){
        $("#menu .item").removeClass("active");
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass("active")) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, by using a span as a wrapper around the icon and a checkbox, you should be able to manipulate the span to check the box, and change the background color.

```
<span id="checkbox-wrapper">
  <i class="fa fa-flask" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <input id="flask" type="checkbox" hidden>  
</span>
```

Here is an example of what the click event might look like in jquery:

```
$("#checkbox-wrapper").on("click", function() {

    var check = !$("#flask").prop("checked");
    var background = check ? "green" : "red";

    $("#flask").prop("checked", check);
  $(this).css({"background-color" : background});
});
```